# What was that big toothy inter-dimensional creature in Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

At the beginning of the *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2* movie, the Guardians are under contract to protect the Sovereign race from some great-big-ugly alien monster thingy, pictured below and seen in the trailers:

[image: Screen shot of movie clip from the *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol 2*, with a giant alien creature with a large mouth and rows of long pointed teeth]

The creature features the following features:

- Huge
- Toothy
- > A hide that's too thick to be pierced from the outside - *Drax (Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol 2.*)
- Spews colourful fire-ball rays
- Yellow interior
- **Appears from what seems to be another dimension**
- Feeds off of Sovereign "<s>Harbulary</s> Anulax batteries"

### What is that alien creature?

Also, how and why can it travel through other dimensions?

Comment: “protect the Sovereign race from some great-big-ugly alien monster thingy” — I think they’re just there to stop it stealing their batteries, rather than protect the whole race.

Comment: @paul Yeah I was over-exaggerating, just like the Sovereign. Although Ayesha did mention something like "we couldn't risk the sacred lives of one of our own", or some such; so there was potential for real harm :)

Comment: +1 for "colo**u**rful", at least some people know how to spell!

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Pfft. We in the US can spell just fine, thank you. It's just that we were one "u" short when naming our country, so we used that one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## [An Abilisk](http://screenrant.com/guardians-galaxy-2-spoilers-leak-james-gunn/) <sup><sub><sup>[1](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Abilisk)</sup></sub></sup>

This new monster is an invention of the MCU and James Gunn. James Gunn originally released the concept art with the monster in the background without giving it a name, however after questions from a fan he confirmed that it is called an Abilisk.

Currently the only source I can provide as hard evidence is the new LEGO set: The Milano vs The Abilisk.

[image: LEGO set]

The Following clip from [this](https://facebook.com/jgunn/videos/10153562475666157/) Facebook video is where James Gunn first reveals the name of the "Big toothy inter-dimensional creature"

---

<sup>1</sup> MCU wikia link.

Comment: When I search for "Abelisk", I get results for Final Fantasy XII. News articles about GotGV2 and the MCU wiki all refer to it as an "Abilisk"

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Ah ok, I was just going of the audio file, which I'll add in a second. Thakns!

Comment: "Hey, James, what's that multi-dimensional alien being?" "It's, um, an <totally original name>, and it's a, um, multi-dimensional being." <- gee, that's deep. Also, that's not exactly what "multidimensional" means.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Don't shoot the messenger, I'm just relaying what I found, which seems to be what the asker is looking for.